# "SQL sometimes times out" - on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, on-topic, off-topic

No question similar to this came up in the fancy box, so I am going to ask it so that it can be referenced.

[Store Procedure Timing out sometimes?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32060/store-procedure-timing-out-sometimes)

It gives code that sometimes times out for the user, meaning that it sometimes runs through and produces results, but sometimes it fails.

Is this an on-topic question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this question should be on topic, because the issue here is the performance of the query, if the timeout length was longer or they had a more powerful machine the query might run 100% of the time.

these are the instances where I can see this happening

- SQL
- http responses being requested from a server

please feel free to add more to this answer